# How not to display system errors in C++?

Tags: c++, system

I have a program that check some information about logical drives but if the drive like A:\ is not in it will display an error, like "

```
Windows - No Disk
Exception Processing Message C00000013 Parameters 75b76 etc
Cancel      Try Again      Continue
```

Is there any way to disable such errors to appear and just let the program continue or automatically press continue button ?
UPDATE:

```
DWORD drives = GetLogicalDrives();
for (int i = 0; i<26; i++)
{
    if ((drives & (1 << i)))
    {
        TCHAR driveName[] = { TEXT('A') + i, TEXT(':'), TEXT('\\'), TEXT('\0') };
        cout<<driveName;
    }
}
```

If i run the code on XP it get the error that A:\ doesn't exists. Is there any way to disable this ?

Comment: You could use a [try-catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4t3saedz.aspx) statement to handle that exception specifically.

Comment: Insufficient information to answer the question.  You posted no source code.  We don't know where this message came from or what APIs you are calling.

Comment: In addition, why isn't your code checking to see if drive `A` is valid or not?  Why wait for an exception to occur in the first place?

Comment: There's an explicit Windows API function to disable this. @Cyber's answer is wrong as the Windows API does not use C++ exceptions.

Comment: Cyber: can you please show an example how to use try catch in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS)`